# MySQL - Update by using a value from sub query on same table

Tags: mysql, correlated-subquery, in-subquery

I have a table 'mytable' and it has following structure and sample data.

```
+----+------------+--------------------+
| id | name       |   password         |
+----+------------+--------------------+
| 1  | Raj        |   somepwd          |
+----+------------+--------------------+
| 2  | Rao        |   abcdefg          |
+----+------------+--------------------+
| 3  | Uday       |                    |
+----+------------+--------------------+
```

I want to update Uday's password with Rao's password.
Can anyone help me with MySQL's update query to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use this query.

```
update mytable as t1,
(select id,`password` from mytable where name = 'Rao') as t2
set t1.password = t2.password
where t1.id = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE mytable 
set 
  password=(SELECT password FROM mytable WHERE name LIKE 'Rao') 
WHERE name LIKE 'Uday'
```

Comment: This query will return an error: `Error Code : 1093
You can't specify target table 'mytable' for update in FROM clause`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: @VirendraJadeja I am not sure which database you are executing the query. Atleast in Oracle the query executes fine without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
update mytable set password = (select password from mytable where id=2) where id=3
```

or you can use self join

```
update mytable t1 join mytable t2 on t1.id = 3 set t1.password = t2.password
where t2.id=2
```

Note: Use id's instead of other columns

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution,Actually above all solutions giving me error.

```
UPDATE mytable as aa, (SELECT password FROM mytable where id =2) as bb SET aa.password=bb.password where aa.id=3;
```